# Run java tests with sudo in intellij

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea, testcontainers

## Context

I've just found about testContainers, a library which can start docker containers and I wanted to test it writing a simple test inside Intellij.

## Problem

The problem is that when i run the configuration in Intellij, the code throws Exception because running docker instructions need sudo permissions.

```
23:18:52.180 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (ping failed)
23:18:52.186 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (ping failed). Root cause NoSuchFileException (/var/run/docker.sock)
23:18:52.187 [main] ERROR org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration. Attempted configurations were:
23:18:52.187 [main] ERROR org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy -     EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (ping failed)
23:18:52.187 [main] ERROR org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy -     EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (ping failed)
23:18:52.187 [main] ERROR org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy -     UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (ping failed). Root cause NoSuchFileException (/var/run/docker.sock)
```

Tried to add current user to docker group
`sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`
Still i can't run the app inside in Intellij, even if i start it with sudo.

## Working alternative

Use `sudo mvn test` directly where i have the pom.

## Question:

Can I make it work inside Intellij?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA has no such option.

Comment: If you add your current user to docker group you don't need to run docker commands with sudo.

Comment: I have similar situation. I am running docker insider WSL. But intellij in Windows. I tried setting up the DOCKER_HOST but that too didn't work.

Comment: I am havind a similar issue as well